# Getting username and password, is this code right or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I have a html login page in html given below

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myform" action="API.html" method="get">
        Username : <input type="text" name="username" required><br /><br />
        Password : <input type="text" name="password" required><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" id="sub" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

and i have another html page which the action page of the previous page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>API INTEGRATION</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<body>
    <script>
        var username = "........";
        var password = "........";

        if ($.get("username") == username && $.get("password") == password) {
            var settings = {
                "async": false,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "url": "https://........../test2/api/v1/sdk_initialize",
                "method": "GET",
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "cache-control": "no-cache",
                    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password),
                }
            }
            var result = $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {

            });

            var token = result.responseJSON;
            var settings = {
                "async": false,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "url": "https://........./test2/api/v1/Events/10?search=All ",
                "method": "GET",

                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "cache-control": "no-cache",
                    "Token": token,
                }
            }

            $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        } else {
            alert("incorrect Login Details");
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to get the username and password from the login page and then want to compare it with my set username and password and if it is correct the do certain task else provide output as incorrect login details.
    but i am always getting an output as "incorrect Login Details" and not the json object even if i use the same login credentials?
        I also want to know `($.get("username")==username && $.get("password")==password)` is this code is right or not?

Comment: From [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), I don't think that is how you use `$.get()`

Comment: You should validate these server side. Anybody inspecting your js code can see the username and password.

Comment: Proper password handling involves: 1) `<input type="password">` 2) Server side validation 3) One-way hash designed for passwords (BCRYPT, Argon2i...). Doing it that way implies the same amount of develpment work than what you're attempting to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer.

As i understood, you have a login form and when form submits it navigates to another page where you validates it.

In this case i can see you are using `method="get"` for a login form. Which is not good in any manner. As it will be appended in the url and it will be visible to the people and is not secure.

Anyway, if this is the case then you can get it from the url:

```
var formdata = window.location.search.split('&');
var user = formdata[0].split('=')[1];
var pass = formdata[1].split('=')[1];

if (user == username && pass == password) {
```

Comment: Will this work even if the form and the action is separate?